# Installing a CGI Proxy on Tomcat

Tags: python, module, environment

I want to setup a proxy for openlayers to use so  I followed these steps:

1. Downloaded the proxy.cgi file from the OpenLayers web site: 
   http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/examples/proxy.cgi
2. Modify the proxy.cgi file to include my domain in the allowedHosts list:

   allowedHosts = ['localhost:6901']
3. Copy the proxy.cgi file to the following folder:

   $TOMCAT_PATH$/webapps/yourApp/WEB-INF/cgi/
4. Modify the file web.xml of your web app by adding the sections below. You find the file at

   $TOMCAT_PATH$/webapps/yourApp/WEB-INF/web.xml

**Comment:** In case the web.xml file doesn’t exist for your webapp, just create it yourself or copy it from another webapp and modify it. (created!)

**Comment:** the “param-value” for the “executable” parameter has to contain the path to your Python installation. (it does!)

```
<servlet> 
      <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class> 
    <init-param> 
      <param-name>debug</param-name> 
      <param-value>0</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
      <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name> 
      <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
      <param-name>executable</param-name> 
      <param-value>c:\python25\python.exe</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
      <param-name>passShellEnvironment</param-name> 
      <param-value>true</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet> 

  <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/cgi-bin/*</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
```

1. Modify the file context.xml of your web app by adding the element below. You find the file at `$TOMCAT_PATH$/webapps/yourApp/META-INF/context.xml`
2. Restart Tomcat
3. To use the proxy with OpenLayers, just include this single line into your code:

   OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/yourWebApp/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

But when I try to use it like:

```
/webappname/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=labs.metacarta.com
```

I get this error:

```
Some unexpected error occurred. Error text was: list index out of range
```

I think its related with os.environ["REQUEST_METHOD"] but I dont know how its related ..

Comment: can you show your code that calls the module, and the module code? (if possible?)

Comment: More info. is needed - Are you running within a CGI? - if so - what, etc... It would also be nice to provide the full traceback properly formatted.

Comment: there it is updated description

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing and Running CGI Proxy Python on Tomcat 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819310/installing-and-running-cgi-proxy-python-on-tomcat-7)

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for an environment variable that isn't defined.

You need to either catch and handle the exception or use `os.environ.get`:

```
try:
    methodq = os.environ["REQUEST_METHOD"]
except KeyError:
    methodq = "default value"
```

Or:

```
methodq = os.environ.get("REQUEST_METHOD", "default value")
```

Comment: That just masks the problem though... If it isn't set (and I am taking a stab it's in a CGI environment), then there should be a "POST", "HEAD", "GET" etc... and that can't reasonably be defaulted... Hopefully the OP will clarify though...

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting :

```
/webappname/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=labs.metacarta.com
```

But the proxy.cgi script is trying to do this:

```
host = url.split("/")[2]
```

Try http://labs.metacarta.com for your url so proxy.cgi has some slashes to split on, or modify it to parse the url a little smarter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You don't install or use cgi proxy on Tomcat.

cgi is for apache server or IIS that are used as a front-end server. Tomcat may sit behind it. The configuration of Apache is detailed in: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

Be warned that OpenLayers warns that its proxy.cgi is only an example and may not have good enough check to stop it from being exploited, i.e. it may run some malicious script.

If you are serving your OpenLayers client page on Tomcat alone and it contains layers from other GeoServer or Mapserver, you can use proxy servlet and specify it as:

OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "sevlet URL on the server that served this page";

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/ServletProxy

https://svn.openxdata.org/Experimental/openXmapper/trunk/gwt-openlayers-server/src/main/java/org/gwtopenmaps/openlayers/server/GwtOpenLayersProxyServlet.java

There are reverse proxy or rewrite sevlet solutions to it, too. Please Google on these.